# Mongoose not updating key value pairs stored with Object Schema

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

This is for rating feature in my application. I want to use the user-mail as key and the users rating as the value

**Eg:**

```
ratings : {
  "user1@gmail.com" : 5,
  "user2@gmail.com" : 4
}
```

I don't prefer using arrays since their could be just a single rating from each user.
I tried inserting a new key value pair in mongo using compass and it worked fine but when I did this using mongoose with type as Object in express, it is not working. Only the first key value pair is stored the user2's key value pair is not getting added.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Schema type : **Object**

I have solved this using the method `markModified("fieldname")` before `save()`.

Example:

```
mongooseSchema.markModified("ratings");

mongooseSchema.save();
```